# iOS 7.1 Autorotation: frame does not change, transform matrix is used instead

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad

I am witnessing a strange behaviour oniOS 7.1, both under the simulator and a real device.

If I set up an empty project in Xcode, using default settings, then add the following method:

```
- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation {

    NSLog(@"VIEW: %@", self.view);
    [super didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:fromInterfaceOrientation];
}
```

What I get is the following traces for the 4 orientations:

```
2014-11-10 12:25:59.190 testingRotation[13148:60b] VIEW: <UIView: 0x7a948980; frame = (0 0; 320 568); transform = [0, 1, -1, 0, 0, 0]; autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x7a948140>>
2014-11-10 12:26:01.415 testingRotation[13148:60b] VIEW: <UIView: 0x7a948980; frame = (0 0; 320 568); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x7a948140>>
2014-11-10 12:26:03.559 testingRotation[13148:60b] VIEW: <UIView: 0x7a948980; frame = (0 0; 320 568); transform = [0, -1, 1, 0, 0, 0]; autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x7a948140>>
2014-11-10 12:26:06.187 testingRotation[13148:60b] VIEW: <UIView: 0x7a948980; frame = (0 0; 320 568); transform = [0, 1, -1, 0, 0, 0]; autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x7a948140>>
```

As you can see, the frame does not change and a transform is used to rotate the view content.

This only happens when using iOS 7. Everything works as expected under iOS 8. Unfortunately I have not been able to test this under iOS 6.

Can anyone give an explanation?